# Unable to add 'SlickGrid9.19.17/lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' (File Name) to the Web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

When I'm publishing my ASP.NET project using Visual studio. I'm getting this which results in Publishing error.

1>Publishing folder SlickGrid9.19.17/lib...
1>Unable to add 'SlickGrid9.19.17/lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'SlickGrid9.19.17\lib\jquery-1.11.2.min.js'.  The semaphore timeout period has expired.

Because of this I'm not able to publish my project. How can I publish my project and resolve this issue.

I have Tried Copy pasting jquery-1.11.2.min.js from my Project folder location to my publishing folder location but it didn't worked out.

Comment: Please check whether the static resource file is in the wwwroot folder, and make sure that the physical path characters of the jquery-1.11.2.min .js file are not too long. Then try again.

Comment: Try to upgrade VS2022 to the latest version, delete the `.vs`, `bin`,`obj` folders, and try again.